# sidefootnote problem

Tags: memoir

I use memoir class and, in some situations, I use the `\sidefootnote` command.
It works but not the right justification.
I've tried with `\newcommand*{\sidefootform}{\rightskip=\z@ \@plus 2em}` but I've got an error message (command already in use).
I've tried with `\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{\rightskip=\z@ \@plus 2em}` but error message.
I've tried with:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand*{\sidefootform}{\RaggedRight}
```

but no effect at all.
Any suggestion?
Thanks
PM

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by »It works but not the right justification«. The notes are set raggedright by default if that's what you mean? `\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{\rightskip=\z@ \@plus 2em}` will work [if placed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) but only reproduces the default setting. If you want the notes justified add `\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{}` to your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by »It works but not the right justification«. The notes are set raggedright by default if that's what you mean?

You can't do `\newcommand*{\sidefootform}{...}` since the command is already defined. It is a unfortunate that the `memoir` manual is a bit misleading here...

`\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{\rightskip=\z@ \@plus 2em}` will work provided it is [placed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) but it will only reproduce the default setting which is probably not what you want.

If you want the notes justified you can add `\renewcommand*{\sidefootform}{}` (i.e. an empty definition) to your preamble.